# Which sorting algorithm is used here?

Tags: algorithm, math, sorting

In a programming event they asked this question.

Question:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K.

Write and algorithm to sort the cards in reverse order **in 7 steps**.

K Q J 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1.

I couldn't trace out the sorting alogrithm.
Which algoritm is used here?

Comment: What is a "step"? A comparison, a swap, something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's something like [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), but with block moves:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 J Q K

8 9 10 J Q K 7 1 2 3 4 5 6
J Q K 8 9 10 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 
J Q K 8 9 10 7 4 5 6 1 2 3 
K Q J 8 9 10 7 4 5 6 1 2 3 
K Q J 10 9 8 7 4 5 6 1 2 3 
K Q J 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 1 2 3 
K Q J 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Update:** actually it might be even simplier: just swap `1` and `K` and `2` and `Q`, `3` and `J` etc. Just seven steps :)

Comment: Well, that's how it's called in my country :). And `hoar` was just a typo.

Comment: Regarding "update", I make that 6 swaps, since the 7 in the middle stays put. I guess the hard part of this question is working out what a "step" is supposed to mean - there's only so many ways to reverse an array, so one you know what "step" means you know which of those ways is the one that has 7 steps, and you can answer ;-)

Comment: In fact I think you could make pretty much any divide-and-conquer approach come out in 7 "steps" with a suitable definition of step: handle 4 blocks of 3, 2 blocks of 6 and one block of 12 in some order (top-down for quicksort, bottom-up for mergesort), and be sure to sneak the 7 into the middle somewhere along the line.

Comment: @Steve no, the seventh step is to swap `7` with `7` :) Well, actually you are right in that any approach can be "tuned" to use 7 steps.

Answer (score 0):

If a step is a swap then [Selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) will order the list in 6 steps.

K Q J 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1

**1** Q J 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 **K**

1 **2** J 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 **Q** K

1 2 **3** 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 **J** Q K

1 2 3 **4** 9 8 7 6 5 **10** J Q K

1 2 3 4 **5** 8 7 6 **9** 10 J Q K

1 2 3 4 5 **6** 7 **8** 9 10 J Q K